# Angular material md-subheader not refreshing its bindings

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have this piece of code:

```
        <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">
            Activities ({{vm.selectedActivities.length || 0}} selected)
        </md-subheader>
```

`vm.selectedActivities` changes. But `{{vm.selectedActivities.length}}` is not refreshed, unless I do something else on the page, for instance resize it. I also put `{{vm.selectedActivities.length || 0}}` outside `md-subheader` and it gets properly refreshed. Is there a way to fix it?

Also I played around with markup rendered with this directive:

```
<h2 class="md-no-sticky md-subheader md-default-theme"><div class="md-subheader-inner"><span class="md-subheader-content"><span>BINDING_GOES_HERE</span></span></div></h2>
```

If I remove `md-subheader` class, everything starts to work, but styling is broken.

Comment: looks like a issue at this directive. You should force a $scope.apply() when you update the vm.selectedActivities. You should report this issue at the oficial Angular Material repository as well: https://github.com/angular/material/issues

Comment: I tried - does not work. Digest cycles are launched ok (other bindings work)

Comment: I will try to help you out at Angular Material GitHub, this is a bug that should be fixed